# Android Studio Lambda expressions are not allowed at this language level

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working on a chat application. I got a demo app from [github](https://github.com/NaikSoftware/stomp-protocol-example-server), the chat app that is working. In some classes they used lambda expressions but it's working fine, but when I copy those code mine is giving this error " Lambda expressions are not allowed at this language level ". Some people said that android studio does not support lambda expressions but the demo app is working on my phone.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

in build.gradle there should be

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

And you should probably use RetroLambda. Look at the demo project's build.gradle file

Comment: where do i put that inside **dependancy** or **android**

Comment: @watchit in your build.gradle file of app module

Comment: Inside android{}

Answer (score 0):

In their Android project they are using RetroLambda -
 a plugin that allows lambdas in lower versions of Java,
 which includes Android (see the plugin at the top --> https://github.com/NaikSoftware/StompProtocolAndroid/blob/master/example-client/build.gradle)

Follow the setup here: https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda